# iOS facebook login without SDK http post Swift/Obj-C

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, http, post

Let me start off by saying the purpose of this code is so I can practice on various other sites with login pages or forms. This is why I do no wish to use Facebook's SDK. So please...
Do not point me to Facebook's SDK (many other questions specifically asking for without SDK have been given SDK answers)

Ideally I would like to create an app that has preset information that will login to a site (such as Facebook) when the app opens or a button is pressed

I'd prefer an answer in Swift but I can read Objective - C and may be able to decipher it

Here is some sample code I've tried:

```
let myURL = NSURL(string: "https://mobile.facebook.com")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")


    let postString = "email=*email&pass=*pass&login=Log In"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let postInt = postString.characters.count

    request.setValue("\(postInt)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-length")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
        }

        if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            let sCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode
            if sCode == 200 {
                // Then do something.
                self.webView.loadRequest(request)
            }
        }


        print("respone = \(response)")
    }
    task.resume()
```

*email = The user's email

*pass = The user's password

note: email, pass, Log In were taken from the form name values on the html code.

Current results- I am able to get the email to appear on opening of the app but the password is blank and it doesn't appear to have attempted a log in.

Please help and let me know if you need any clarifications

PS I've been looking for about a week now to no avail so I apologize if the answer is somewhere. I am not completely familiar with terminology to look for it.

Comment: So you basically want to know the url which you can send username and password to to log a user into facebook? Or is something else not working?

Comment: If that is a solution sure. But that url I use above should work fine. I'm wondering how to log in to the app with the code above. So when the web view appears, I'm logged in.

Edit: I would like to be able to repeat this code for other websites with only changing the body elements. I understand other factors may come in to play and would be willing to learn those as well.

Comment: By injecting the received cookies and auth tokens and whatever into the webview - that is some research you have to do since I have no idea what stuff fb needs

Comment: I tried attempting an authentication but it didn't seem to give any results. I think the form is separate from authentication tokens but I could be wrong. Do you by chance have example of code for a specific site I could compare that may be similar. That's really what I'm after.